# difference list (Prolog)(Logic Programming)

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

I have a problem solving the difference list problem with paper-pencil not by the helping of SWI Prolog ( in these days i am preparing my logic programming exam).

Here is the question:

```
q(X) :- p(X - []).
p([X|Y] - Y).
p([X|Y] - Z) :- p(Y - [X|Z]).
```

Explicitly give the set of all ground terms t for which the query ?- q(t). succeeds. State a formal
definition of the set in closed form (i.e., do not use a recursive definition).

Answer is :

> {[t1, . . . , tn−1, tn, tn−1, . . . , t1] | n > 0, ti
>       is a ground term for all i ∈ {1, . . . , n}}

I used [1,2,3,2,1] and it gave me true as an expected answer.

I could not understand what the steps are in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `t = [t1,t2,t3, ... , tn]` be a list.

`q(t).` will succeed if `p(t - []).` succeeds.

`p(t - []).` succeeds if `p([t2,t3,...,tn] - [t1]).` succeeds (third rule).

`p([t2,t3,...,tn] - [t1]).` succeeds if `p([t3,...,tn] - [t2,t1])` succeeds, etc.

This will actually only end up succeeding if at one point the second rule gets applied (otherwise we will end up calling `p([] - _).` which does not match any rule available), that is if we have `p([ti,ti+1,...,tn] - [ti+1,...,tn]).`.

The second list `[ti+1,...,tn]` is actually `[ti-1,ti-2,...,t2,t1]` according to the way it is constructed in the third rule.

Therefore `q(t).` succeeds iff `ti-1 = ti+1, ti-2 = ti+2, ..., t2 = tn-1, t1 = tn`, which means `t = [t1,t2,...,ti-1,ti,ti-1,...,t2,t1]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I am not so clear about "The second list [ti+1,...,tn] is actually [ti-1,ti-2,...,t2,t1] according to the way it is constructed in the third rule." why do we cut down the list? Also while you solved the problem firstly you applied first rule than third rule finally second rule, but prolog executes the code top the bottom?

Comment: Prolog executes top to bottom but the second rule can only be executed when we have two lists [X|Y] and Y (first list is the second with an extra element at the beginning), so until we reach this point we execute the third rule.I don't understand what you mean by "why do we cut down the list".

Comment: "The second list [ti+1,...,tn] is actually [ti-1,ti-2,...,t2,t1] according to the way it is constructed in the third rule" that explanation is not clear for me how can you write it down?

Comment: "`p([t2,t3,...,tn] - [t1]).` succeeds if `p([t3,...,tn] - [t2,t1])` succeeds, etc" Look at this to see how the second list gets more elements: they are the elemnts of `t` in reverse order, until the second goal succeed, at which point it will contain `[ti-1,ti-2,...,t2,t1]`